# Unit simplex is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

If we have a sum $a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$, where $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $x_i\geq 0$ and $\Sigma_{i} x_i =1$.

Following set maximizes previous sum:

$S(x)=\{x \space:\space \Sigma_{i} x_i =1$ and $x_i=0$, if $a_i<\max_{j\in \{1,...n\}}\{a_j\} \space \}.$

What is the right way to show that the set $S$ is closed? If we have a sequence $\{x_k\}\subset S$ so that $x_k \rightarrow x$, as $k\rightarrow \infty$. It's clear that $x_k \in S$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, but does that prove that the limit $x \in S$?

This might be a silly question, but I'm not sure what is enough for this proof.

Comment: It makes no sense to have $x$ in $S$ and $x$ as a free variable in the set definition.

Comment: @copper.hat True, it's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \{i | a_i = \max_k a_k \}$.  Then
$S = \{ y | y_i \ge 0, \sum_k y_k =1 \} \cap \{ y | y_k = 0 \ \forall k \in I \}$.

Since the functions $y \mapsto y_k, y \mapsto \sum_k y_k$ are continuous, it follows that $S(x)$ is closed.

Another way is to notice that $f(x)= \sum_k a_k x_k$ is continuous; the
simplex $\Sigma = \{ y | y_i \ge 0, \sum_k y_k =1 \}$ is compact and so $f$
has a maximum $\bar{f}$ for $x \in \Sigma$. Then
$S = f^{-1} \{ \bar{f} \}$, which is the inverse image of a closed set with a continuous function and hence closed.

Comment: Glad to help!  $$$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequences to approach the question. As you say, let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $S$ such that $x_k\to x$. Now you need to prove that $x$ is also in $S$.

> It's clear that $x_k \in S$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, but does that prove that the limit $x \in S$?

No, that's not enough; it's just going in circles. In order to prove the result, you'll need to apply the actual definition of $S$, at least twice. You'll use it once to translate the desired claim $x\in S$ into a handful of equations, and in order to show that those equations hold, you'll apply the definition of $x_k\in S$.

Alternatively, you can use the general formulation of closed sets: see copper.hat's answer.

Comment: When the boundary (union of closed segments $[e_1,e_2],[e_2,e_3],...,[e_n,e_1]$) is contained in $S$ and $S$ is a part of a plane, then can that information be used for trivial proof?

Comment: Maybe something like that works; I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind. Be careful with the boundary, though. First, the union of segments is not necessarily contained in $S$. At the same time, when $n>3$, the boundary of $S$ may be greater than $1$-dimensional; if so, it is much larger than the union of segments.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: when the set $S$ is acually the intersection of two closed sets, e.g.  $\{x,y,z \space : \space x+y+z=1 \}$ and $\{x,y,z \space : \space x,y,z\geq 0 \}$, then does the result follow?

Comment: Which result are you asking about now?

Comment: Sorry, that question was irrelevant. Thanks for your answers!